# Scalaz : monoid not found

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm following this scalaz tutorial : http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/FoldLeft.html :

```
scala> object FoldLeftList {
         def foldLeft[A, B](xs: List[A], b: B, f: (B, A) => B) = xs.foldLeft(b)(f)
       }
defined module FoldLeftList

scala> def sum[A: Monoid](xs: List[A]): A = {
         val m = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
         FoldLeftList.foldLeft(xs, m.mzero, m.mappend)
       }
sum: [A](xs: List[A])(implicit evidence$1: Monoid[A])A
```

This is shown entered into scala sbt console but I'm attempting to run it in standalone scala file :

```
object main extends App {

  trait FoldLeft[F[_]] {
    def foldLeft[A, B](xs: F[A], b: B, f: (B, A) => B): B
  }
  object FoldLeft {
    implicit val FoldLeftList: FoldLeft[List] = new FoldLeft[List] {
      def foldLeft[A, B](xs: List[A], b: B, f: (B, A) => B) = xs.foldLeft(b)(f)
    }
  }

  def sum[M[_]: FoldLeft, A: Monoid](xs: M[A]): A = {
    val m = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
    val fl = implicitly[FoldLeft[M]]
    fl.foldLeft(xs, m.mzero, m.mappend)
  }

}
```

But I receive compiler error :

```
[error] \src\main\scala\custom.scala:12: not found: type Monoid
[error]   def sum[M[_]: FoldLeft, A: Monoid](xs: M[A]): A = {
[error]                              ^
[error] \src\main\scala\custom.scala:13: not found: type Monoid
[error]     val m = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
[error]                        ^
```

Should Monoid be imported, if so where is located ?

Update :

Seems I missed Monoid def  :

```
  trait Monoid[A] {
    def mappend(a1: A, a2: A): A
    def mzero: A
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard for scalaz imports is `import scalaz._, Scalaz._`. You can later remove the `Scalaz._` part and just pick what you need.